# How to set Remote user to Jersey Client?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mocking, jersey, cgi

I am doing some unit testing for a Jersey based webserice. I am using Jersey test framework.

In the servlet, I have this piece of code:

@POST

```
public void insert(@Context UriInfo uriInfo, @Context HttpServletRequest request)
{
   ......
}
```

When post the request in unit test, I have this:

```
WebResource r = resource().path("/root");
r.post();
```

Everything works but since the test server is running locally on Grizzly I cannot get the remote user from request. Is there a way to mock that in the unit test?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process:

- [Add remote_user to the resource config](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.3.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html#addProperties%28java.util.Map%29)
- [Override the Request method](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.3.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/filter/HttpMethodOverrideFilter.html)